# Styled component not being respected between files?

Tags: css, next.js, styled-components

For whatever reason, the buttons (defined by `AboutItem`) are displaying light blue backgrounds when I hover over them. I want to make it `#282828`.

In a separate file I define some styled components for Buttons:

```
export const Button = styled.button`
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 0em 1em;
`;

export const InfoButton = styled(Button)`
  color: grey;
  &:hover {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
`;
```

which I then use:

```
interface AboutNavProps {
  selected: boolean;
}

const AboutItem = styled(InfoButton) <AboutNavProps>`
  color: grey;
  background-color: ${props => props.selected ? "#282828" : "transparent"};
  text-align: center;
  &:hover {
    background-color: #282828;
  }
`;


export function AboutNavbar() {
  const router = useRouter()
  useEffect(() => {
    router.prefetch("/method");
  }, [])

  return (
    <AboutNav aria-label="Navbar">
      <AboutItem as="a" href="method" selected={router.pathname == "/method"}>How It Works</AboutItem>
      <AboutItem as="a" href="about" selected={router.pathname == "/about"}>About</AboutItem>
      <Logo />
    </AboutNav>
  );
}
```

Is there a reason for this? I don't understand why the light blue overrides the color I define for the hover.

Comment: Shot in the dark, is it related to the CSS cascade? i.e. are the styles being output but overridden in CSS?

Comment: The `background-color: #282828` is being overridden by `background-color: lightblue` when I inspect elements

Comment: looks like a issue being caused by some component higher up in the hierarchy